# How to convert input box to be a dropdown in angular8

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

i have a requirement, where in initially that will be a input fields, based on selection of one dropdown, number code will be autogenerated to the other input field.The autogenerated code of input field should be editable, where in it must be a dropdown with search field, and the search field must contain either name or number search.
I used ngx-typeahead plugin to make this work, but i am not satisfied with what i have done, i need a dropdown to be shown when clicked on that input field, and based on search it must show me the values based on search.
Any idea of how can this be implemented?

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-typeahead-abp3n6?file=src%2Fapp%2Flists%2Fstatic-list.ts)

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Group Agent</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Group Code" name="groupCode"
                formControlName="groupAgent" name="groupCode" ngxTypeahead 
                [taList]="staticList" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="handleStaticResultSelected($event.target.value)"
                (taSelected)="handleStaticResultSelected($event)">
            </div>
```

TS:

```
 public handleStaticResultSelected (result) {
    if(result == ''){
      this.getGroupCodeDefaultValues()
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use angular multiselect dropdown

Comment: i have given demo here, here i shouldnt use any extra framework, i have used bootstrap4, also here one value at a time is to be selected

Comment: could you please help me out, how can this be handled?

Comment: Okay. Get in touch with you once i will do it.

Comment: yes please thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-typeahead-abp3n6?file=src%2Fapp%2Flists%2Fstatic-list.ts

i have henerate the demo. You can see it wokrs ok as what you want. i have used ngs-completer module. If wokring ok then plaese inform me so i can put it on answer box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212071/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-rbc9662).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ng2-completer package.Link is here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-completer

Now following the step you have to follow

Step 1
In app.module.ts

> `import { Ng2CompleterModule } from "ng2-completer";`

Step 2
hero.component.ts

> `import { CompleterService, CompleterData } from 'ng2-completer';`

Step 3
In constructor of hero.component.ts

```
 constructor(private completerService: CompleterService) {
 this.dataService = completerService.local(this.dataArray}
```

step 4
In template file of hero.component.ts

```
<h1>Search color</h1>
<ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i will work on this if i face any difficulty will ping you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Primeng p-dropDown.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown
or https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect
Chack this out it is easy to style as well.

Comment: Thanks for response, but primeng is big plugin and is not allowed in my application